# Creating a Two-Dimensional Array with Concrete Positions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to create a custom array:

In php I would define as follows:

```
$myarray[100][80] = 1;
```

But I don't know how to do it in objective-c...

I don't need an array `[0][0],[0][1],[0][2], ...` I only need concrete positions in this array `[80][12], [147][444], [46][9823746],...`

The content of these positions always will be = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you would use a dictionary rather than an array as they are always 0,1,2 keyed so something along the lines of:

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSString *key = @"80,12";

NSDictionary *items = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:one forKey:key];
```

Then to pull them out again you would use the objectForKey: method.

You cannot put ints directly into arrays or dictionaries that's why it is wrapped in the NSNumber object. To access the int after getting the NSNumber out of the dictionary you would use something like:

```
NSNumber tempNum = [items objectForKey:key];
int i = tempNum.intValue;
```

See the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a full explanation of the NSDictionary class. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I an not a PHP master but I believe in php arrays are not real arrays they are hash tables right?

Anyway, I think you are looking for NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary class.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like a bitset than an array.

Allocating so many cells for that seems useless, so maybe you could revert the problem, and store the positions in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well in objective c we can use NSMutableArray to define 2-D arrays.

See the following code, it might help you

```
NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSMutableArray *col = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[col addObject:row];
NSString *obj = [[col objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```